# FFMPEG - Get creation and/or modification date

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, mp4

I'm trying hard to get the modification date from a MP4 file hosted on my server.

I tried the following library:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4
```

Without any luck. All I get is duration and a few other fields but I'm not able to get modification date. I tried ffprobe as well and it is not there either.

Any suggestions??

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean the unix mdate? Or a specific metadata field in the mp4 spec - in which case: which one? i.e. what is the four-letter code/tag of the metadata field?

Comment: I'm not sure about the format. I need it for the video metadata.

Comment: I thought I could get anything that comes with the file. Between all the metadata, there is always creation and modification date so I thought I could get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked for you, and indeed, mp4 has a modification time entry in the MDHD, but it's not exported (see [code](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavformat/mov.c;h=92bf2f894099f0e4d50b6184f19852769c372139;hb=HEAD#l1045)). You can file an [enhancement request](https://www.ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html) to get this metadata feature added to FFmpeg, but right now it won't help you and you'll need another tool to read this field.

Answer (score 22):

Get `creation_time` with `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -v quiet input.mp4 -print_format json -show_entries stream=index,codec_type:stream_tags=creation_time:format_tags=creation_time
```

To view all tags:

```
ffprobe -v quiet input.mp4 -print_format json -show_entries stream_tags:format_tags
```

I can't find any reference to `modification_time` so consider using [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) or [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/fr/MediaInfo).

Comment: It says that -v is not an option for ffprobe, when I remove it, it says the same about -print_format

Comment: You may be using an ancient version. I assure you the parameters are correct for the recent versions. Check https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html

Comment: I didn't get `creation_time` in the output.

Comment: @RichardWiseman it'll only show it if it's present in the format metadata

Answer (score 7):

A simpler alternative to aergistal in terms of output is

```sh
$ ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0  -show_entries stream_tags=creation_time -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

which will just print the creation time like so:

```
2020-07-23T11:51:02.000000Z
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. (Not sure why the other answerer thought it was useful to print the result in JSON when the original question didn't specify that requirement.)

Comment: is there any way to get this as epoch time

Answer (score 1):

The creation_time might be the wrong place to look at. I have a video that has both

"creation_time": "2022-08-11T03:01:40.000000Z",

and

"com.apple.quicktime.creationdate": "2022-08-10T12:18:23-0700"

and I know the `2022-08-10T12:18:23-0700` is the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

If ffmpeg is not getting you the creation date metadata it simply may not be present in the file. The utility 'mediainfo' can show a lot more information, it may be worth investigating its output against your mp4s.